Deadlock in AudioWorkIntervalCreate
Sometimes when I call AudioWorkIntervalCreate the call hangs with the following stacktrace. The call is made on the main thread.
mach_msg2_trap 0x00007ff801f0b3ce
mach_msg2_internal 0x00007ff801f19d80
mach_msg_overwrite 0x00007ff801f12510
mach_msg 0x00007ff801f0b6bd
HALC_Object_AddPropertyListener 0x00007ff8049ea43e
HALC_ProxyObject::HALC_ProxyObject(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int) 0x00007ff8047f97f2
HALC_ProxyObjectMap::_CreateObject(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int) 0x00007ff80490f69c
HALC_ProxyObjectMap::CopyObjectByObjectID(unsigned int) 0x00007ff80490ecd6
HALC_ShellPlugIn::_ReconcileDeviceList(bool, bool, std::__1::vector<unsigned int, std::__1::allocator<unsigned int>>&, std::__1::vector<unsigned int, std::__1::allocator<unsigned int>>&) 0x00007ff8045d68cf
HALB_CommandGate::ExecuteCommand(void () block_pointer) const 0x00007ff80492ed14
HALC_ShellObject::ExecuteCommand(void () block_pointer) const 0x00007ff80470f554
HALC_ShellPlugIn::ReconcileDeviceList(bool, bool) 0x00007ff8045d6414
HALC_ShellPlugIn::ConnectToServer() 0x00007ff8045d74a4
HAL_HardwarePlugIn_InitializeWithObjectID(AudioHardwarePlugInInterface**, unsigned int) 0x00007ff8045da256
HALPlugInManagement::CreateHALPlugIn(HALCFPlugIn const*) 0x00007ff80442f828
HALSystem::InitializeDevices() 0x00007ff80442ebc3
HALSystem::CheckOutInstance() 0x00007ff80442b696
AudioObjectAddPropertyListener_mac_imp 0x00007ff80469b431
auoop::WorkgroupManager_macOS::WorkgroupManager_macOS() 0x00007ff8040fc3d5
auoop::gWorkgroupManager() 0x00007ff8040fc245
AudioWorkIntervalCreate 0x00007ff804034a33

In the scenario where I am seeing this have multiple programs that are started at the same time, and each of them is calling AudioWorkIntervalCreate. When the deadlock appears I can see multiple programs being stuck with the same stacktrace. If I kill one of them, many of the remaining ones gets out of the deadlock, so I am guessing that this is some kind of deadlock inbetween the multiple apps.
All of the programs use that same name for the workgroup as in: AudioWorkIntervalCreate("myWorkGroup", os_clockid_t::OS_CLOCK_MACH_ABSOLUTE_TIME, nullptr);
Does this name need to be system wide unique? Any ideas what is causing the deadlock?
